# Как организовать отладку кода на Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Привет, хочу узнать как можно организовать анализ кода в реальном времени, так как есть чужой код с ошибкой, которую нужно исправить, а там полнейший хаус, в ручную проанализировать каждую строчку ни нервов ни мозгов не хватит. Ошибка связана с редиректом и геолокацией.

Comment: https://wpmag.ru/2013/otladka-wordpress-debug-bar/

Comment: PhpStorm + XDebug